# Php, reflection, how to remove "final" declaration?

Tags: php, reflection

I want to test a class which is declared:

```
"final class testme"
```

and cannot be mocked. How to remove the "final" keyword with reflections?

Comment: What do you mean it can't be mocked? Are you trying to unit test this? Reflection class can't change a `final` declaration

Comment: Generator.php said: "Class "Testme" is declared "final" and cannot be mocked.

Comment: if reflection can changes "private, protected" attributes, I cant believe they cant change "final" attribute...

Comment: I think it can change the `final` status of a function but not the class itself. It might be possible to do it with [runkit](http://us2.php.net/runkit) and runkit_class_adopt but I've never tried.

Comment: Any solution @JohnSmith ??

Comment: not really, but it was php 5.4 then, might with 7.4 it's doable

Answer (score 0):

Yea, got the solution.

https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2019/03/28/how-to-mock-final-classes-in-phpunit/

there is a "wrapper" to load php files and remove "final" in the meantime.